# giving an easier name to many columns and applying function to them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to apply many functions to certain columns in my df. But there are many columns. Is there any way to give these groups of columns a certain name and then apply functions to them?

I am looking for something like

```
df[['One', 'Two',...'Sixty']] = values
values.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could first create a list of column names and then use [`pd.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) as follows:

```
values = ['One', 'Two',...'Sixty']

df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(values)].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the columns then use the apply option in pandas:

```
cols_to_group = ['col1', 'col2']

df.loc[:, cols_to_group] = df.loc[:, cols_to_group].apply(my_function)
```

my_function can contain the functionality you need to apply to the group.

Answer (score 1):

If *performance* is not an issue, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) :

```
cols = ['One', 'Two',...'Sixty']

df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
```